# Insert rows from one table into another table, while creating the incremental values?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Edit:** OOPS, apparently in my test tables, I forgot to set id as autoincremental. After setting it the query works as expected. Sorry everyone!

I have two tables, **Source** and **Dest**.

Source has the fields **field1** and **field2**

Dest has the fields **id**, **field1** and **field2**. Id is the primary index and autoincremental.

I have tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO dest (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2
FROM source
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM dest 
                 WHERE (source.field2=dest.field2)
                 );
```

But then, the id in each copied row is 0.

How can I say in my query that I want to copy field1 and field2, and create a new autoincremental value for id?

Comment: Are you sure there is an `auto_increment` on `dest.id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the exists statement with a left join:

```
INSERT INTO dest (field1, field2)
SELECT field1, field2
FROM source
LEFT JOIN dest
ON source.field2 = dest.field2
WHERE dest.field2 IS NULL;
```

The id should auto-increment automatically, too. If not, check that it does in the table's definition (`show create table dest`).

Comment: Oops, after reading your comment I realized I forgot to set id as autoincremental in my test tables... So the original query worked.

Answer (score 0):

The query should increment `dest.id` if it's declared as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Please post the output of

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE dest
```

Also, if you only want unique values of `field2` to be in `dest`, you may declare `dest.field2` as `UNIQUE` and just use this:

```
INSERT IGNORE
INTO    dest
SELECT  field1, field2
FROM    source
```